# Python extract values from text using keys

Tags: python

I have a text file in the following format of `Key Value`

```
--START--
FirstName Kitty
LastName McCat
Color Red
random_data
Meow Meow
--END--
```

I'm wanting to extract specific values from the text into a variable or a dict. For example if I want to extract the values of `LastName` and `Color` what would be the best way to do this?

The `random_data` may be anywhere in the file and span multiple lines.

I've considered using regex but am concerned with performance and readability as in the real code I have many different keys to extract.

I could also loop over each line and check for each key but it's quite messy when having 10+ keys. For example:

```
if line.startswith("LastName"):
    #split line at space and handle
if line.startswith("Color"):
    #split line at space and handle
```

Hoping for something a little cleaner

Comment: LastName and Color could be grabbed with a regular expression. The random data would be near impossible to extract without specific markers in it

Comment: Sorry wasn't very clear, I'm wanting to ignore the `random_data` and pass over it. I thought about regex but a little concerned about performance and readability. Idealy I would like to be able to define a list of tokens to extact `tokens = ['LastName', 'Color']`

Comment: Well, the first question that usually gets asked is what have you tried?

Comment: Updated original post. I'm wondering if there's something cleaner than what I posted

Comment: Can there be multiple instances of FirstName or any other field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tokens = ['LastName', 'Color']  
dictResult = {} 
with open(fileName,'r') as fileHandle: 
   for line in fileHandle:
      lineParts = line.split(" ")
      if len(lineParts) == 2 and lineParts[0] in tokens:
           dictResult[lineParts[0]] = lineParts[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is in something called sampletxt.txt, this would work. It creates a dictionary mapping from key -> list of values.

```
import re  
with open('sampletxt.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()
keys = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Color']
d = {}
for key in keys:
    d[key] = re.findall(key+r'\s(.*)\s*\n*', txt)
```

Comment: Might want to do `re.findall()[0]`, otherwise the value is a list of a single value

Answer (score 0):

This version allows you to optionally specify the tokens

```
import re
​
s = """--START--
FirstName Kitty
LastName McCat
Color Red
random_data
Meow Meow
--END--"""

tokens = ["LastName", "Color"]
if len(tokens) == 0:
    print(re.findall("({0}) ({0})".format("\w+"), s))
else:
    print( list((t, re.findall("{} (\w+)".format(t), s)[0]) for t in tokens))
```

#### Output

```
[('LastName', 'McCat'), ('Color', 'Red')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off the other answers, this function would use regular expressions to take any text key and return the value if found:

```
import re
file_name = 'test.txt'

def get_text_value(text_key, file_name):
    match_str = text_key + "\s(\w+)\n"

    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        text_to_check = f.readlines()

    text_value = None
    for line in text_to_check:

        matched = re.match(match_str, line)
        if matched:
            text_value = matched.group(1)

    return text_value

if __name__ == "__main__":

    first_key = "FirstName"
    first_value = get_text_value(first_key, file_name)
    print('Check for first key "{}" and value "{}"'.format(first_key,
                                                           first_value))

    second_key = "Color"
    second_value = get_text_value(second_key, file_name)
    print('Check for first key "{}" and value "{}"'.format(second_key,
                                                           second_value))
```